# zero's or singularity of a complex valued function at $z=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

We have a function 
$$f(z)=e^{\frac{-1}{z^2}}$$ then $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f(z)=0$$
 Is $z=0$ zero's of $f(z)$? Or at $z=0$ 
$f(z)$ has any type of singularity.please help. 
Thanks

Comment: That limit equality is only true if $z$ approaches $0$ along the real axis.  What if $z = iy$ with $y$ real and $y \to 0$?

Comment: Expand $e^{-\frac{1}{z^2}}$ as Taylor series & find its type of singularity

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=e^{-\frac{1}{z^{2}}}=1-\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{z^4}-...$$which contains infinite number of negative powers of $z$.

So $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.